# Pull from DB only those project that are needed in CA

Tags: sql, cognos

I have two Queries in Cognos Analytics (v11.0.13), one is pulling project financials from one database and the other one project details from another database (cannot be pulled at once with one query).

Is it possible in CA to pull only those projects, that are in financial instead of pulling all projects?

I used to do that in MS Power Query that I made string out of column and used it as parameter in SQL query.

```
   project
   project1
   project2
   project3

SQL: ...WHERE PROJECT IN ('project1', 'project2', 'project3')
```

Is that possible to do something similar in CA?

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to do the same detail filter with the predefined strings.  Alternatively you could create a prompt using a query against the first database and then use that prompt to filter the query against the second database.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using multiple prompt pages, JavaScript, and a value prompt.

- Prompt page 1 has the prompts required for your financial query.
- Create a miniature version of your financial query to return only the
  project numbers.  Be sure it has the same filters.  Use this new
  query to populate a value prompt.
- Prompt page 2 contains the value
  prompt.  Use JavaScript to select all of the values in the value
  prompt.  This value prompt provides the values for the parameter for
  your project details query.
- Prompt page 2 should also have all
  object hidden and automatically run the FINISH or NEXT action.

Take a look at https://github.com/dougpulse/Cognos -- specifically https://github.com/dougpulse/Cognos/blob/master/CognosScripts/Prompts.js and https://github.com/dougpulse/Cognos/blob/master/CognosScripts/PromptAutoFinish.js and a usage example in https://github.com/dougpulse/Cognos/tree/master/ReportSpecifications (Parameter Value Automation).